# Multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS headers in Wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, cors

I would like to allow multiple (two, more specifically) origins using Wordpress' functions.php instead of using apache/nginx directives. Currently I have this:

```
function my_customized_rest_cors() {
   remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
   add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
           header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://my.1stsite.com' );
           header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS' );
           header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
           header( 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link', false );
           header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type' );
           header( 'Vary: Origin' );
           return $value;
   } );
}
```

How should I modify it?

Comment: I found an answer to my question in this thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242206/is-it-safe-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-cors-origin-errors-with-a-php-he/242327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

> `<origin>`
>   Specifies an origin. Only a single origin can be specified.

So you will need to make this dynamic, and output the origin that matches the actual request.

You find that info in the `Origin` request header. But make sure it is on the “list” of the ones you want to allow first (`in_array` can easily be used for such a check) - otherwise, if you just respond the content of the `Origin` header back as this point unchecked, you would practically open this up to *every* origin.